# How to add Alert box if Null before re-prompting after a break;

Tags: javascript

I'm a Javascript student and I was wondering the proper syntax to wrap an Alert box around the prompt to say "Hey, wait a minute, you need to complete the form!" and have to click "OK" before it breaks and re-prompts the user for a string or int/float. I know this is redundant but it's just for learning-sake.

Here's what I tried but I get the alert after I enter a string/int/float or if it's null regardless. :(

```
function breakTest() {
var loopBoolean = true;
var myValue = "";
while(loopBoolean) {

  myValue = prompt("Enter data", myValue);

    if (myValue==null); 
      alert("Hey, wait a minute, you need to complete the form!"); break;

      if (myValue) {
        loopBoolean = false;
        alert (myValue)
      }
}
```

}

And this is the orignial code that works properly without my alert box implementation:

```
function breakTest() {
var loopBoolean = true;
var myValue = "";
while(loopBoolean) {

  myValue = prompt("Enter data", myValue);

    if (myValue==null) break;

      if (myValue) {
        loopBoolean = false;
        alert (myValue)
      }
}
```

}

Thanks

Cheers,
Json Segel

Comment: You are missing brackets after first if and Your code always execute break after first if. Omitting the fact that in first if You should have continue instead of break.

Comment: The brackets are note _required_ if its a single line statement. They are advisable though.

Comment: @somethinghere I know this, but with code snippet given by Json he needs it, of course he could change his if to: if(..) alert(..); and it would work fine..

Comment: True that. There are a couple of improvements I've outlined below to make it simpler and understandable. (it doesn't really help that the indentation feels a but mucky in his post, though)

Comment: I learned about the brackets not being needed for one liners, but I should just add it for best practices. Thanks for that. Hey somethinghere, can you post my code using the proper indentations so I can learn best practices? I know xhtml/css and in this book the indentation is all funky for those languages as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes brackets is not needed for one liners, but they improve the readability of code. @somethinghere yes I see what You write as an answer and beeing fairly You overtake me in this by couple of seconds ;), and also upvote for Your answer.

Comment: Thanks to both of ya, Tadek & Somethinghere. :)

Comment: @Json Segel You're welcome :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified method would be:

```
function breakTest() {
    var loopBoolean = true;
    var myValue = "";
    while (loopBoolean) {//Run the loop while loopBoolean is true
        myValue = prompt("Enter data", myValue);
        //Prompt user to enter data.
        if (myValue) { //Checks if data has been entered
            loopBoolean = false; //Set the loopBoolean to true if data is found.
            alert(myValue) //Show the data
        } else {
            //Else alert the user to input data again after user clicks ok the loop continues
            //untill the loopBoolean is false.
            alert("Hey, wait a minute, you need to complete the form!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Everyone's code was close, but this one worked perfectly. The only thing I changed was, is I declared myValue = ""; again below, because if not, it was appearing in the box with the text "null," as it should per RegEx. Perfect fix, thank you for the proper code Gopu.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a simple bit of logic, heres one that works:

```
function breakTest() {
    var myValue = "";
    // you don't need a loopBoolean because you will break the loop manually
    while(true) {
        myValue = prompt("Enter data", myValue);
        // First of, your value will not be null but empty, so ""
        if (myValue == ""){ 
            alert("Hey, wait a minute, you need to complete the form!"); 
            // also, you want to reprompt to input a value, so you want to continue
            // to redo the loop (you could use break to end this here and now)
            continue;
        } else {
            // else you want to alert the value and break the loop
            alert (myValue);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then potentially return the value instead of alerting, and use break to escape the loop if the value is *not* empty (as in `else { break; } } return myValue;`. Then you could do `var globalValue = breakTest();` to let the user assign a new value.

Also, `break;` and `loopBoolean` in your function do the same thing. Once `loopBoolean` is `false` you stop the while loop, but a while loop gets stopped with the `break;` keyword as well, so you could just use that.

### Modified snippet

I personally really wouldn't style it like this (I think your indentation could be a lot clearer, only indenting when you are inside a statement), but this should do the trick

```
function breakTest() {
var loopBoolean = true;
var myValue = "";
while(loopBoolean) {

  myValue = prompt("Enter data", myValue);

    if (myValue == ""){ 
        alert("Hey, wait a minute, you need to complete the form!");
        // You dont want to break here, actually, as you want to rerun the loop.
        // So I'll comment out the break. Now it will prompt until you enter something!
        // break;
    }
    if (myValue) {
        loopBoolean = false; // <- this does the same as using break: it ends your loop
        alert (myValue)
    }
}
}
```

I just want to make it clear that you can omit the `loopBoolean` or omit the `break` and use the `loopBoolean` there (consistency!) and that there is no point to this loop, as you are breaking it either way and therefor not actually looping. I'm thinking you actually want to *not* break the loop after the 'input' alert to repeat until somebody inputs something.

Comment: I think for this case, since I'm a beginner they're using very rudimentary code so that the students (and myself) can build on the simple stuff we've learned before-hand until it becomes memorized. I totally understand the logic of this code and it makes sense, but for the sake of using the rudimentary and somewhat I understand, redundant code, do you think you could possibly provide me a snippet of this fix using the code above and working with the current perimeters? Much appreciated if possible. Ty!

Comment: I've amended my answer to just modify your original. For hints on indentation, check my modified code at the top. About the brackets, its safer to put them there as you want to break after your alert, which means its a two-line statement. Also, the second if is better of as an `else` since we know the value is not empty, so it must contain something!

Comment: If thats the right answer, do you mind marking it as such? Cheers and good luck with the next steps in coding! :)

Comment: Well it got me closer, but when you click OK when the input is blank, it doesn't break and re-prompt until the user has entered in data. Once you hit OK, it exits the prompting completely.

Comment: I think I know what happened here, you misunderstood the word `break` which will _break away_ from the loop. Remove the word `break` and it will reprompt because the loop only ends once you set your `loopBoolean` to `false` (which, in this case, does the same as just using a `break` - it ends your loop). Just remove the break.

Answer (score 0):

You are terminating the if statement. Just remove the semicolon.

```
   if (myValue==null)
     enter code here alert("Hey, wait a minute, you need to complete the form!");
```

There is no need for break here.

Comment: Well this is interesting, if I remove that semicolon, if I enter text, nothing prints to the page, but if I hit cancel on the prompt, it does display my alert message.